# vector equality in c++ map function

Tags: c++, dictionary

There is a piece of code which I changed to a more clear code. Here it is:

```
map <TwoWayHostPair, Traffic> traffic;
static map <TwoWayHostPair, Traffic>::iterator trafficItr;

trafficItr = traffic.find(hostPair);
if (trafficItr == traffic.end()) { 
      trafficItr = traffic.insert(make_pair(hostPair, Traffic())).first;
}
```

This is not whole code. this is just a part of code. so it wont compile is not the answer, now it compiles

`traffic.first` is an attribute of class `TwoWayHostPair`. I think `if(trafficItr == traffic.end())` means that if `trafficItr` is not equal to `traffic` which may not be correct.

Does anyone knows if my claim is true? Also if it is true, when `trafficItr` is equal to `traffic` what would be the result? Is it something like `trafficItr == traffic.begin()`

Comment: A map is not a vector.  See e.g. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find to learn about what the result of `find` means.

Comment: yeah, my error :( sorry about inconvenience

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a correct `c++` code. `find` returns an iterator to an element in the map or the end iterator if the element is not found. Assigning a map to the result of find just won't compile. Also you can't compare a map to the end iterator of another map. Also note you have to pass to find an instance of TwoWayHostPair or something convertable to such instance.

The idea of code like:

```
map <TwoWayHostPair, ClassA> variableA, variableB;
//variableA is set to a proper value

map <TwoWayHostPair, ClassA>::iterator iter;
iter = variableB.find(TwoWayHostPair_instance)

if(iter == variableB.end())
     //do something
```

Is to do stuff only if the element is not found in the map.

Comment: @AlokSave adding more information I know it is not complete but that is the essence.

Comment: Even before comparing, the assignment to `variableA` won't compile

Comment: This is probably better off as a comment; pointing out that the example code doesn't even compile basically invalidates the entire question!

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I wanted to include the corrected version which is not quite possible as a comment.

Comment: @AndyProwl I have fixed that too.

Comment: I think, I shouldnt have changed the code :) since the code was quite long, i thought it is better to make it easier, seems like I demolished all the code. I m correcting the question, thanks for help, guys